# How to pass HTML META tags from inside a Google App SANDBOX to the parent window?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, sandbox

Using Google App Script UI creating a simple *file upload* script, it works, but there is a Catch 22. Google wraps your HTML code in an IFRAME SANDBOX and any/all meta-tags in your HTML page are not passed to the parent wrapper.

I do realize security is the reason Goggle uses IFRAME/SANDBOX, however, one should be able to set some common tags such as, title and viewport, as that would pose no security risk to the sandBox.

Here is a snippet of what I tried, but did not work in a Google App Script, Yes I tried just regular meta tags, but they don't pass to the parent.

```
function setParentMetaTag() {
    var viewPortTag=document.createElement('meta');
    viewPortTag.id="viewport";
    viewPortTag.name = "viewport";
    viewPortTag.content = "width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;";
    window.parent.document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(viewPortTag);
}
setParentMetaTag();
```